# Stuck with exiting from a loop in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

The problem is that I don't know how to exit from my loop.

```
printf ("Do you order fish? (Y/N): ");
scanf  ("%c", &f);

while((f == 'y')||(f == 'Y'))
{
  do {
    fish = getfish_choice();
    printf ("Total of you fish is %.2lf\n", sum);
    printf ("Do you want to order more fish?(Y/N)");
    scanf  (" %c", &morefish);
  }
  while ((morefish=='Y')||(morefish=='y'));
}

Printf ("Hello");
```

How could I exit this loop so the output of my code will read Hello?

Answer (score 2):

You have a `while` loop whose condition involves checking `f`.  But you never modify `f`.

So perhaps that first `while` should actually be an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the outer while loop to an if: 
`if(f == 'y'||f == 'Y')`

Answer (score 1):

What's happenning is that when `Y` or `y` is entered, you manage to break out of the inner loop, but you're still stuck in the outer loop. (`f` is never modified)

You don't even need two loops:

```
printf ("Do you order fish? (Y/N): ");
scanf  ("%c", &morefish);

while ((morefish=='Y')||(morefish=='y')){
    fish = getfish_choice();
    printf ("Total of you fish is %.2lf\n", sum);
    printf ("Do you want to order more fish?(Y/N)");
    scanf  (" %c", &morefish);
}

printf ("Hello");
```